# PoolingDataSource Properties for High Concurrent Web-Application

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am working on a web-application and I need to configure a `PoolingDataSource` from Apache Commons DBCP in order to support some level of user-concurrency. I tried `BasicDataSource` but it does not seems to be the solution. The point is that in `BasicDataSource` I can set some parameters like these bellow:

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
dataSource.setUsername("sa");
dataSource.setPassword("");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:");
dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
```

And it will initialize 5 `Connections` and keep them in the pool and do its thing. I can also get some statistics using a `BasicDataSource` like *NumActiveConnections* and *NumIdleConnections*. Now, with a `PoolingDataSource`, how do I set these values properties to the DataSources? and how can I get some connection statistics from the pool?

And one last question, in order to consume a connection, should I setup a DataSource each time I need Connection or should I setup a unique DataSource in a static variable and create all Connections from there? How should I manage the DataSoures and Connections?

I currently setup the DataSources using the following code:

```
public static DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI) {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectURI,null);
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, null);
    ObjectPool<PoolableConnection> connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool<>(poolableConnectionFactory);
    poolableConnectionFactory.setPool(connectionPool);
    PoolingDataSource<PoolableConnection> dataSource = new PoolingDataSource<>(connectionPool);
    return dataSource;
}
```